# How can I properly using this struct template nested in a struct template?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, visual-c++-2022

```
enum ByteOrder_e
{
    MM,
    II,
};
template<ByteOrder_e O>
struct ByteOrder_s
{
    enum Version_e
    {
        Small,
        Big
    };
    template<Version_e V>
    struct Version_s
    {
    };
};
template<ByteOrder_e O, typename ByteOrder_s<O>::Version_e V>
void Open()
{
    using Version = typename ByteOrder_s<O>::Version_s<V>; //MSVC considers this line to be wrong
}
```

ConsoleApplication1.cpp(22,52): error C2760: syntax error: '<' was unexpected here; expected ';'
ConsoleApplication1.cpp(22,55): error C2760: syntax error: ';' was unexpected here; expected 'expression'

Comment: Why is `Version_e` a member of `ByteOrder_s` at all? It doesn't care about the template parameter, so why is it a member? That is, every `ByteOrder_s<T>` should be using the same `Version_e`.

Comment: @NicolBolas This is a small reproductive demo. There is a complicated reason in my real project.

Answer (score 1):

Indicates that `Version_s` is a class template by introducing the `template` keyword:

```
using Version = typename ByteOrder_s<O>::template Version_s<V>;
//                                     ^^^^^^^^^^
```